# How can I enable cross-origin framing on a jekyll site hosted on an Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, jekyll, tableau-api, azure-static-web-app

I'm building a static site using jekyll and I'm trying to embed my tableau public dashboard to this webpage.  When I try to embed it in an iframe I get this below error saying that I can't embed it.  I've tried to do some research and it looks like it's because cross-origin framing isn't enabled.

[image]

I've tried adding the following section to my _config.yml which doesn't work

```
# Custom headers
  webrick:
    headers:
      Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; 
      X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://public.tableau.com
```

I also tried to find some setting on Azure that would allow it but I'm coming up empty.

How can I enable cross-origin embedding so I can embed this dashboard?

Comment: Hi @MyNameHere, can you please add the error image into text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `X-Frame-Options` header is set to `sameorigin` on tableau.com server. This prevents the page from being rendered in an iframe on pages other than the original host.
This is set on the server and you cannot fix it from the client side.

However, you can embed a specific dashboard from tableau using Share -> Embed Code option on dashboard page. Just paste the given code in your jekyll page and it should create a working iframe with dashboard.

Comment: I had tried this before and it didn't work, but I tried again and messed with the code formatting and got it to work.  I'm not sure why but having too many spaces between the ending closing div tag like this `</div>                <script type='text/javascript'>` and the script tag was making it break.  By removing those spaces it works now.